# How to target all matching elements with jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

The below jQuery should show the first 5 elements in both unordered lists, but it only displays the first 5 elements in the first list. The first 5 elements in the second list are not displaying. How can jQuery be used to display the first 5 elements in all lists that have the same class name?

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.list').children().hide();
  $('ul.list').children().slice(0, 5).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is saying give me all of the children of all the lists and give me the first five. It is not saying give me the first five of each list. To use slice, you would need to select each list and loop over it. It would be better to use a better selector.

Use nth-child selector to select the first elements in each list.

```js
$("ul li:nth-child(-n+5)").addClass("active")
```

```css
li {
  display: none
}

li.active {
 display: list-item
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

And because you said it has to be "hide and show"

```js
$("ul li").hide().filter(":nth-child(-n+5)").show()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

The wya to get your code to work is looping over the uls and referencing their own list.

```js
$('ul.list').children().hide();
$('ul.list').each(function() {
  $(this).children().slice(0, 5).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do purely with jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: What is not jQuery/JavaScript about it?

Comment: Using .show() and .hide() instead of adding a class for CSS.

Comment: So use hide and show.... Instead of add class, replace it with `show`

Comment: I guess I am also unclear why the combination of the element selector is not working with slice correctly. Not really understanding why the original code does not target both lists.

Comment: Because you select all the children from both elements. It is one big jQuery collection. You then say from this collection, I want the first five items. It has no idea you want 5 items from each.

Comment: I updated it with how you would need to code it to use slice

Comment: That is interesting, and your new answer has brought great clarity. Nice that this answer has the two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery or JavaScript necessary. Just use plain CSS with `li:nth-child(n+6)`:

```css
li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.list').children().hide();
  $("ul li:nth-child(-n+5)").show()
});
```